# Obtain a precise(1km specific) series of altitude values using Google Earth/Map API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, kml, google-earth

**Using the Google Earth(or Maps) API what functions do I use to obtain the heightmap/Altitude for a specific area(at a precision of kilometres rather than a precision of longitudinal degress)?**

For example if I have the location Lat=11 Long=12, can I obtain the altitude for that location? I am aware that google's altitude may not be accurate and wont have the precision of 5 metres or maybe even 1km precision but thats ok(its for simple fun Google Earth App so accuracy in altitude isn't required).

My code below can obtain the current altitude at the position where the mouse currently sits, but is there function call to obtain a **series of altitude values for a given location**?

```
google.earth.addEventListener(ge.getWindow(), 'mousemove', function(evt) {

   if (event.getDidHitGlobe()) {
     var lat  = event.getLatitude();
     var long = event.getLongitude();
     var groundAltitude = ge.getGlobe().getGroundAltitude(latitude, longitude);
     if (groundAltitude) {
        alert(groundAltitude.toFixed(2));
   }
});
```

Is this the only way? Note this is precise to the 1 longitude/latitude, can I get more precise(like the 1km specific)

```
function obtainAreaAlt(startLong, endLong, startLat, endLat) {

     var alt = {};
     while (startLong < endLong) {
         var origLat = startLat;
         while (startLat < endLat) {
           var a = ge.getGlobe().getGroundAltitude(startLat, startLong);
           if (a)
              alt[""+startLat+","+startLong] = a.toFixed(2);
           startLat++;
         }
         startLong++;
         startLat = origLat;
     }

     return alt;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the Elevation Service of the Google Maps API. It accepts an array of locations, (lat/lon values) or a path.

Demo here:

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/elevation-paths

Documentation here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#ElevationService

Note that there are usage limits!

Answer (score 0):

with the google earth plugin you will want move to the location were you are picking your elevations and wait for the elevation datadata to finish downloading to the browser to get a better elevation resolution.

to determine if the elevation data has finished downloading use ge.getStreamingPercent()

http://earth-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/examples/streamingpercent.html

if you are zoomed out too far the earth globe is populated with a low resolution terrain model